# Overriding incorrect EDID display physical dimensions

Tags: nvidia, xorg

My monitor is a Samsung 27SA850, which has physical dimensions 59.8cmx33.6cm. However, for some reason, EDID is determining that the display's physical dimensions are actually 52.0cmx32.1cm, which results in an odd non-square DPI and messes up font hinting.

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep -B 2 resolution
screen #0:
  dimensions:    2560x1440 pixels (520x321 millimeters)
  resolution:    125x114 dots per inch
```

XRandR and `nvidia-settings` also report the incorrect 520x321 millimeters dimensions. I attempted to tell Xorg about my actual screen dimensions by creating a `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-monitor.conf` file containing:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier             "<default monitor>"
    DisplaySize            598 336
EndSection
```

But Xorg seems to be ignoring it. The relevant section of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` still says:

```
[    24.165] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung SMS27A850 (DFP-5): connected
[    24.165] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung SMS27A850 (DFP-5): Internal DisplayPort
[    24.165] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung SMS27A850 (DFP-5): 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    24.166] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[    24.169] (==) NVIDIA(0):
[    24.169] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    24.169] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    24.169] (==) NVIDIA(0):
[    24.169] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    24.169] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-5:nvidia-auto-select"
[    24.169] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 2560 x 1440
[    24.172] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (125, 114); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong; do I need to be more specific in my Section than just `<default monitor>`? Any ideas on how to force Xorg to accept my corrected physical dimensions?

(Note: I'm finding it difficult to Google my way out of this as I normally would because Xorg/Ubuntu insist on changing the rules with regards to Xorg configuration priority with seemingly every single release, so even advice from 2016 appears to be woefully outdated...)